# A button when pressed from another page reloads the page being viewed by all visitors. Which languages are needed to be learnt for this?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm learning JavaScript but I want the following thing in my little (self-started) project as soon as possible.

Suppose the page of my website is `www.mywebsite.com/myPage.html`

Here is a scenario that 10 users are viewing `myPage.html` from my website. As I make any change to `myPage.html` from server (being admin), I want all viewers of `myPage.html` to see refreshed page with new changes taken effect just after I make any change in `myPage.html`. It should be very fast.

For this I think I'll have to create a button which will refresh the page `myPage.html`. As I'll make changes to `myPage.html`, I'll press that button and that button will reload every viewer's browser's page (`myPage.html`). And they will see the result of modified `myPage.html` in their browsers.

Kindly explain your answer properly, since I'm a beginner. Which Languages are needed for this?

Comment: Use polling methods like ajax or real time push methods to know whether there is any change in server so that you can reload the page from client side with javascript.

Comment: what @HarishAnchu said. for example take a look at socket.io (http://socket.io/).

Comment: What you are asking for is not a beginner level question. You are not likely to understand the answers given. What you need is a complete solution, which means hiring a developer.

Comment: @gilly3 which languages are needed to be learned for my task to work perfectly?

Comment: You'd need to learn a server-side language (such as PHP), a way to get info off a database (for example, SQL) and also JavaScript/DOM methods.  It is rather complicated to set up such a system - it is likely to require hours of work and could potentially be rather buggy.  Regardless, you might want to start learning a few  languages first, as you'll only be able to do these sorts of things by learning a language for each area to create this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

i think the best option here would be some kind of push implementation / web sockets ... here are a few links to get you started in the right direction ...

[Websockets : Using modern HTML5 technology for true server push](http://www.abrandao.com/2013/06/25/websockets-using-modern-html5-technology-for-true-server-push/)

[Push Notifications to the Browser With Server Sent Events](http://html5hacks.com/blog/2013/04/21/push-notifications-to-the-browser-with-server-sent-events/)

Comment: which languages are needed to be learned for my task to work perfectly?

Comment: the first link i picked because its a php web server but you can implement in any server side language ... clientside javascript ... you don't have to build from scratch as others have mentioned socket.io is an implementation of this using node.js and js in client... i think you already know the technologies you just have to pick which solution is best for your needs

Answer (score 0):

In the case of socket.io in client side(browser) subscribe every client with a particular channel and make the page reload with javascript when request from server via that channel is recieved. And in server you can broadcast message to that particular channel whenever you want to reload the page.

Comment: I don't know anything about socket.io. How to subscribe viewers?

Comment: In the case of socket.io you must have backend server with socket.io service hosting. So if you need a quick remedy you can use one of the readymade push service. For eg: http://pusher.com/

Comment: which languages are needed to be learned for my task to work perfectly?

Comment: Mostly real time application are wrote on ruby or nodejs. So you need basics of one of these language

Answer (score 0):

you can create an AJAX function that is executing in intervals(like every 10 seconds) and this function will connect to server to ask for any update from mysql, so if there's any updates! you notify the user.
so you should create a table in DB to be updated with page update info when you update a page.

AJAX(asynchronous javascript and xml ) is a technology connect to your server without having to use Forms to post, and you can refresh part of your page automatically.

now here is an example:
I wanted to create an online chat, so here is the code:
this code use ajax to post to ChatNotifyController.php to see if theres anyone online,if there's any it will notify the user.

```
//notify user if someone has or had send a message
setInterval(function(){

xmlhttp.open("POST" , "../controller/ChatNotifyController.php" , true);

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
     if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
     {
         if(xmlhttp.status == 200) 
         {
             if((xmlhttp.response).length > 4)
             {
                    var friendName = (xmlhttp.response).replace(/^\s*$[\n\r]{1,}/gm, '');
                    var responseArea = document.getElementById( friendName + 'ChatArea');

                    var x = friendName ;

                    if(x.indexOf('.') > 0)
                    {
                        x = x.replace('.', '\\.');
                    }

                    var link = $('#' + x);
                    var input = $('#' + x + 'ChatInput');
                    var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
                    e.which = 13;

                    if(link.length > 0)
                    {
                        link.click();
                        input.trigger(e);
                    }
                    else
                    {                           
                        var html = "<li><a class=\"onlineUserLink\" id=\"" + friendName + "\" onclick=\"chat(" + "'" + friendName + "'"  + ")\" >" + friendName + "</a></li>";   
                        html += "<div class=\"chatDialog\" title=\"'" + friendName + "\"' id=\"'" +  friendName + 'ChatDialog' + "'\">";
                        html += "<div class=\"chatArea\"" +  " id=\"'" +  friendName + "ChatArea" + "'\">" + "</div>";                                          
                        html += "<input class=\"chatInput\"" + " id=\"'" +  friendName + 'ChatInput' + "'\" size=\"21\"  onkeydown=\"chatController(event , '" +  friendName + "' , '" +  window.user + "')>" + "</div>";

                        window.onlineArea.innerHTML += html;

                        var THIS = $('#' + x  + 'ChatDialog');
                        $(function() {      
                            THIS.dialog({
                                stack: false
                            });
                        });

                        link.click();
                        input.trigger(e);
                    }
             }
         }
         else 
         {
            //alert("Error during AJAX call. Please try again #003");
         }
     }
};
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xmlhttp.send("user=" + window.user);

} ,5000);
```

Comment: hmm, so I'll need to learn ajax for my task to get completed. Any other thing which I'll need to achieve my objective? But I want it to be very quick just I make change to my file, page being viewed by others should be refreshed instantly not after 10 seconds.

Comment: thats ok, as you can see I used 5000 as my seInterval() argument,  you can use 1000(1 second) or less, but it has more overhead. and yes you really need to learn AJAX.

Comment: Thanks, any other language needed for this task?

Comment: actually AJAX is not a language, it is a javascript technology, you just need to learn javascript with AJAX, and I assume you know PHP and MySQL.

Comment: PHP and MySQL are also needed?

Comment: @MuhammadRehanQadri: it's one of the ways (rather common at that) to perform this sort of thing.  AJAX is simply a name for requests made to servers without having to reload the page using JavaScript - it's a misnomer to say that it's a technology in itself.

Comment: Ajax is not a technology in itself, but rather an umbrella term used to describe how several existing tech- 
nologies such as JavaScript, the Document Object Model (DOM), and Extensible Markup Language 
(XML) can be used together to create Web applications that are more interactive and that remove the 
need for entire web pages to be refreshed when only part of the page is changing. From Beginning Ajax 
Published by Wrox.  @Qantas 94 Heavy: thanx